# Copy of string function and error- stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c

My code:

```
void CopyString(char psSource[], char pcDestination[]) {
unsigned char ucCountCharPosition;
    for(ucCountCharPosition = 0; psSource[ucCountCharPosition]; ucCountCharPosition++) {
        pcDestination[ucCountCharPosition] = psSource[ucCountCharPosition];
        }
    printf("%s", pcDestination);  }

int main() {
    unsigned char psSource[] = "test";
    unsigned char pcDestination[] = "";
    CopyString(psSource, pcDestination);
    return 0;
}
```

And I have a problem with exception thrown:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pcDestination'
>   was corrupted.

I think that this loop is endless, but in this position `psSource[ucCountCharPosition]` I can't use function something like sizeof (because of my homework requirement).

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: sizeof is not a function.

Comment: indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned char pcDestination[] = "";
```

This defines a one-byte array on the stack, and initialized it to all zeros.

You don't have enough space allocated for the string you're trying to copy.

Try:

```
    unsigned char pcDestination[5];
```

You have another problem: your function leaves the destination sting not nul-terminated.